# How to get focused to a selected li using navigation keys in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class='share-hold'>
   <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
   <div class="share">
      <div class='input-hold'>
         <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div class="share-drop">
         <ul class="dropdown-notif">
            <li><a>testmail@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail2@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail3@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail4@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail5@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail6@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail7@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail8@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail9@test.com</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>testmail0@test.com</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.share-drop .dropdown-notif{
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 200px !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.share-drop .dropdown-notif li{
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 5px  !important;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.share-drop .dropdown-notif li a{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.frsh-wrapper article:last-child .user-grp li:last-child .share-drop .dropdown-notif{
    top: -204px;
}
.share-drop .dropdown-notif li.selected{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```js
$('.share-drop .dropdown-notif li').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('a').text();
    $(this).parents('.share').find('input').val(value);
    $('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').hide();
});
$(".share .input-hold input").keyup(function() {
    $(this).parents('.share').find('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').show();
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').hide();
    }
});
$(function() {
    var li = $('.share-drop .dropdown-notif li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.next();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which === 38) {
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.prev();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I need to focus and scroll to the list elements when it is added with the class selected. I tried the above code to achieve it. Can some one spot me whats wrong with my code and help me to find some solution for it. Thanks in advance. 
Below is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/MCxbS/1

Comment: Put a textbox their with visibility 0 and focus it through Code and it will work.

Comment: I didn't get u gupta. A working fiddle may help me out.

Comment: Can you try this one, document.getElementById('idelem').scrollIntoView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All u need to add the following line to your code.

```
$('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').scrollTop($('.selected').position().top);
```

Check out the below fiddle
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MCxbS/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple css.

```
First wrap <a> with <li> and css would be li>a:focus{your style}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didn't work in my case. Is there any other ways could be suggested.

Comment: i think u didnt get my question. while navigating my li it should scroll to the active class thats what i need.